How to "join" 2 functions in Oracle SQL where the result from one function is a param to another
I have this function:
select POD
from get_error_rate_by_pod(:P26_REPORT_WEEK,:P26_ERROR_TYPE);

And I need to feed every result from the above query into the function below as param 2:
select * 
from p49_get_data(:P26_REPORT_WEEK,POD,:P26_ERROR_TYPE);

and basically "union" these results together
Can I do with with a query? Or do I need to create a function with loop + accumulator?
I can change the 2nd function if needed to accept a series of PODS, or a regex (which, I'd rather not), but I'm hoping it isn't necessary

I have this function ... what is the name of the function?  Please label your code.

It's in the question already: get_error_rate_by_pod

From Oracle 12, you can use CROSS JOIN LATERAL:
SELECT d.*
FROM   get_error_rate_by_pod(:P26_REPORT_WEEK,:P26_ERROR_TYPE) e
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT * 
         FROM   p49_get_data(:P26_REPORT_WEEK,e.POD,:P26_ERROR_TYPE)
       ) d;

or CROSS APPLY:
SELECT d.*
FROM   get_error_rate_by_pod(:P26_REPORT_WEEK,:P26_ERROR_TYPE) e
       CROSS APPLY p49_get_data(:P26_REPORT_WEEK,e.POD,:P26_ERROR_TYPE) d;

Which for the setup:
CREATE TYPE pod_obj IS OBJECT (pod NUMBER);
CREATE TYPE data_obj IS OBJECT (pod NUMBER, data NUMBER);
CREATE TYPE pod_tab IS TABLE OF pod_obj;
CREATE TYPE data_tab IS TABLE OF data_obj;

CREATE FUNCTION get_error_rate_by_pod(
  i_week NUMBER,
  i_type NUMBER
) RETURN pod_tab PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  PIPE ROW (pod_obj(1));
  PIPE ROW (pod_obj(2));
  PIPE ROW (pod_obj(3));
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION p49_get_data(
  i_week NUMBER,
  i_pod  NUMBER,
  i_type NUMBER
) RETURN data_tab PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  PIPE ROW (data_obj(i_pod, 4));
  PIPE ROW (data_obj(i_pod, 5));
  PIPE ROW (data_obj(i_pod, 6));
END;
/

Both output:



POD
DATA




1
4


1
5


1
6


2
4


2
5


2
6


3
4


3
5


3
6



fiddle

I didn't even know that was a thing! Woah!
